# Drag a Line with d3.drag-event, on a raster

Tags: javascript, d3.js

since two days, I'm trying to move a line in simple 10x10 Raster, using the mouse.
I solved this without any issues, with complex svg-"Symbols" but the simplest Elements bring me to my borders…

Ok, simple line with a g-tag:

```
var svg = d3.select("#drawing");
const graph = svg.append("g")
  .attr("id","1")
  .attr("ponter-events","fill")
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragGraphicStart)
    .on("drag", dragGraphic)
    .on("end", dragGraphicStop));
graph.html("<line class='coldbrinewater graphic' x1='10' y1='10' x2='50' y2='50' />");
```

Now of Course, before the first drag, this line doesn't have a Transformation, so I check this before reading a Position:

```
var xPos, yPos;
function dragGraphicStart() {
  var trans = d3.select(this).attr("transform");      //Prüfen ob bereits ein Transform existiert
  if (trans == null || trans == "" || trans == "translate(0)") { //kein Transform vorhanden
    xPos = 0;
    yPos = 0;
  }
  else {                                              //Transform gefunden, startwerte ermitteln
    trans = trans.replace(",", " "); //I don't know why, sometimes I got a comma between x and y-value
    trans = trans.substring(trans.indexOf("(") + 1, trans.indexOf(")")).split(" ");
    xPos = parseInt( trans[0]);
    yPos = parseInt( trans[1] );
  }
}
```

And then I try to move the line:

```
function dragGraphic(d, i) {
  xPos += Math.round(d3.event.dx / raster) * raster;
  //xPos += d3.event.dx;
  yPos += Math.round(d3.event.dy / raster) * raster;
  //yPos += d3.event.dy;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + xPos + " " + yPos + ")");
}
```

with the commented lines xPos += d3.event.dx (and y) it works fine but not if I like to calculate the raster before.
I have no idea why, but then I can see in the console, that translate-attribute often only has one Parameter or is empty. like this:
**transform"translate(30)"** or **transform=""**

I built a (non) working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Telefisch/3oecj6wd/

Thank you